# Best approach to handle postgres table that will hold foreign keys of multiple tables

Tags: postgresql, database-design, foreign-key

I am looking for the best way to model a table that will contain a foreign key to multiple tables. I have a table called `actions` that holds text values like `Add` `Update` `Remove` etc. Another table called `objects` will hold types of all the other tables I have, for example `Bills` `Notes` `Invoices` etc. The idea is to have a `actions_objects` table, that will connect an action to an object, but I should also be able to add the `id` of the object table.

```
actions
--------
id   |    label
 1   |     Add

objects
-------
 id  |   type
  2  |   Note 

actions_objects
----------------
action_id  | object_id | object_relation_id

   1             2             23
```

For now I have a way to do this without utilizing any database relationships. I have a field called `object_relation_id` in the `actions_objects` table that holds the id to the object type table, and I then manage the connecting logic in the code (based on the `type` field in `objects`). So in the above example, 23 is the id for an entry in the `notes` table.

I'm not sure if this solution is very scalable, especially as there may be new object types added to the `objects` table. So I wanted to know if there is a way to model this better in the database itself. I'm not an expert with relational databases and have used it in standard scenarios mostly. So I may be missing some obvious patterns that can be used. Any help, or hints in the right direction would be highly appreciated, even if it's to tell me that I may be approaching this incorrectly.

Update: So after reading through some references, I have decided to use  3rd table `actions_objects_entity` This table links a `actions_objects_id` to a foreign key. It has a column for each object type, which is a foreign key to that table. It does mean I have to add a new column if a new object type is added, but this is rare and since all columns are nullable should not cause too much trouble.

Thanks!

Comment: PostgreSQL is an RDBMS.  Do you know the theory of the relational database management system?  It's freely available: https://web.archive.org/web/20070612235326/http://www.acm.org/classics/nov95/toc.html

Comment: Thank you @GerardH.Pille, while I'm no expert as I stated in my question (and indicating I'm aware that PostgreSQL is an RDBMS), and the link is certainly useful, this was not very helpful.

Comment: The intention was not to give you a fish, but to learn you how to fish.  You're walking into a quagmire.  Turn around ASAP.